# Libgdx:Save and getback files in android

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I have a text as string and i have to save it in a new or already created folder with my own extension to file name. User should also able to copy and use these files.I have goggled through many tutorial but all most all are confusing.Is there any simple way in **libgdx**(**android** platform) to save a string as file with my own extension and getting it back from list of files in memory.
What i need is:

1. A function to save file to new or already existing folder(available for user).Giving String as parameter.
2. Another function to get List of ".my" files in specified folder.

Comment: theres a nice [tutorial](http://steigert.blogspot.be/2012/03/5-libgdx-tutorial-files.html) by steigert about Files. hope it helps

Comment: Do you just want to save data in the file to access it later, like saving highscore for example? SharedPreferences is an easy way to do that without all the hasle

Comment: I am pretty sure he is looking for `files` because he needs to copy them too. You can't just copy shared preferences around, and that stores only key-value pairs.

Answer (score 1):

Save:

```
    public boolean saveToFile(String fileName)
    {
        FileHandle fileHandle = Gdx.files.local(fileName + ".txt");
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fileHandle.writer(false));
        try
        {
            bw.append("stuff");

        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
        finally
        {
            try
            {
                bw.close();
            }
            catch (IOException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
```

and Read:

```
        FileHandle f = Gdx.files.local(fileName + ".txt");
        BufferedReader r = null;
        try
        {
            r = new BufferedReader(f.reader());
            String line = null;
            while((line = r.readLine()) != null)
            {
                //read the lines
            }
        }
        catch (GdxRuntimeException e)
        {
            //file does not exist yet
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch(IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally
        {
            if (r != null)
            {
                try
                {
                    r.close();
                }
                catch (IOException e)
                {
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Although technically, if the user needs to be able to copy the files around, then you're probably better off with `external` instead of `local`.